# Catching an Exception from a PendingIntent

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for a way to catch an exception thrown when a `PendingIntent` fires, specifically an `ActivityNotFoundException`.

Here's the code I'm using to set the `PendingIntent`

```
Intent addIntent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_EDIT, CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI );
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent( R.id.button_add, PendingIntent.getActivity( context,
            REQUEST_CODE_ADD,
            addIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT ) );
```

Simply wrapping that with a try/catch won't work because the exception wouldn't happen until the `PendingIntent` is actually activated.  Any ideas?

Comment: You could wrap it in a class and put the activation in a try catch

Comment: I can only imagine the case of `ActivityNotFoundException` . This is the Only Exception it can generate i guess . Well As a workaround you can first check the `Activity` is registered or not using `PackageManager` and `PackageInfo`.

Comment: I'm going to try wrapping it in an Activity.  Did you have something simple in mind when you said wrap in a class?